# Basic terms for the elements of an observation, sample?

Tags: statistics, terminology

I'm trying to write a database schema for measurements in a variety of categories, and am having trouble coming up with names for some basic elements.

Let's assume we are gathering heart rate and blood pressure measurements from a group of people.

Each observation is composed of the individual being measured, the time the measurement was taken, and the amount of the measurement.  What are each of these called?

What is the name for the type of measurement being taken (heart rate or blood pressure in this example)?

The collection of individuals is the sample, correct?  If so, what is the term for the collection of observations?

Please feel free to revise the question, as my lack of knowledge makes it hard to ask accurately.  I can come up with names myself, but after failing to find anything in some statistical glossaries, I'm curious if there are canonical names for these basic elements.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use these:

Heart rate and blood pressure measurements and time: data

Collection of individuals: sample

Collection of observations: sample data or dataset

Also, see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

You're likely to get a variety of answers.

Since, software design favours shorter names rather than paragraphs, here are my suggestions:

- Individual being measured: **subject**
- Time measurement was taken: **sample time**
- Amount of the measurement: **sample value  (or observation)**
- Type of measurement (e.g. heart rate, blood pressure, etc.): **variable** (they are in fact random variables)
- Collection of individuals: **subjects**  (of the trial)
- The collection of observations: **sample values**